# How to decode the contents of a file in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I read the file in .net.This file is in encoded format.now i have to decode the file.can you help me how to do this in C#?

My encoded file format is

```
DARHnAyyakAALdDALdDALWGALY.AAAEQWAAAHQO
DARJMAyyakAALshALshALjEALoTAAAEA4AAAKcI
DARKwAyyakAAL2wAL2wALvkAL0VAAABJIAAAD$O
DARHnAyyvqAALXCALbkALUYALYXAAAD3MAAAHA6
DARJMAyyvqAALnXALrRALiwALmgAAAEmsAAAKUK
DARKwAyyvqAALzeAL3EALtdALxIAAABFYAAAEBC
DARHnAyzEwAALXlALXlALP7ALU7AAAEpMAAAG5Q
DARJMAyzEwAALlkALlkALeEALjYAAAGysAAAKTs
```

i have to decode this file in c#.please help me..i am having the logic in java.but i don know hot to do t in c#.

```
private void update(String s){
int exp = decode(s.substring(1,5));
exp += 20000000;
int dt = decode(s.substring(5,11));
int op = decode(s.substring(11,15));
int hi = decode(s.substring(15,19));
int lo = decode(s.substring(19,23));
int cl = decode(s.substring(23,27));
int v = decode(s.substring(27,33));
int ni = decode(s.substring(33,39));
append(""+exp,dt, op/100.0f, hi/100.0f, lo/100.0f, cl/100.0f, v, ni);
}

private int decode(String s)
{
int n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
  int c = (int)s.charAt(i);
  if (c >= (int)'A' && c <= (int)'Z')
    c = c - (int)'A';
  else if (c >= (int)'a' && c <= (int)'z')
    c = c - (int)'a' + 26;
  else if (c >= (int)'0' && c <= (int)'9')
    c = c - (int)'0' + 52;
  else if (c == (int)'$')
    c = 62;
  else if (c == (int)'.')
    c = 63;
  else
    c = 0;
  n <<= 6;
  n += c;
}
return n;
}
```

Comment: So you have a file 'encoded' (it looks like) by allowing your cat to walk around with capslock on, and you'd like to 'decode' it to get a cat out? If that's not what you want to do, then please be more specific. My psychic powers are imperfect.

Comment: @Robert Allan That file is encoded because it should not be in readable format.and to reduce the file size also.

Comment: @Dan yea my file is encoded.now i must decode the file.now that file is not readable.now i want that file to be read.for this purpose i should decode the file.

Comment: "That file is encoded because it should not be in readable format" - encryption is what's used to prevent reading of the format. Encoding *might* achieve the same result, but it serves a different purpose. Are you sure you don't mean encryption?

Comment: @Dan, best comment I've seen in a long time. :)

Answer (score 0):

This translates almost directly into c#:

```
   private void update(String s)
    {
        int exp = decode(s.Substring(1, 5));
        exp += 20000000;
        int dt = decode(s.Substring(5, 11));
        int op = decode(s.Substring(11, 15));
        int hi = decode(s.Substring(15, 19));
        int lo = decode(s.Substring(19, 23));
        int cl = decode(s.Substring(23, 27));
        int v = decode(s.Substring(27, 33));
        int ni = decode(s.Substring(33, 39));
        //append(""+exp,dt, op/100.0f, hi/100.0f, lo/100.0f, cl/100.0f, v, ni);
    }

    private int decode(String s)
    {
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            int c = (int)s[i];
            if (c >= (int)'A' && c <= (int)'Z')
                c = c - (int)'A';
            else if (c >= (int)'a' && c <= (int)'z')
                c = c - (int)'a' + 26;
            else if (c >= (int)'0' && c <= (int)'9')
                c = c - (int)'0' + 52;
            else if (c == (int)'$')
                c = 62;
            else if (c == (int)'.')
                c = 63;
            else
                c = 0;
            n <<= 6;
            n += c;
        }
        return n;
    }
```

The only thing I am unsure of is the append statement. Not sure if that is supposed to add the numbers together or build a string from them.

Assuming it is a string, it would be something like:

```
        var sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(500);
        sbText.Append(exp).Append(dt).Append(op/100.0f).Append(hi/100.0f).Append(lo/100.0f).Append(cl/100.0f).Append(v).Append(ni);
        var sText = sbText.ToString();
```

Comment: Which encoding did you determine his input to be?

Comment: Absolutely no idea whatsoever. Seems like a homegrown encryption. I just made the code work :).

Comment: The decode function seems remarkebly similar to the CharToSixBit function you see in some Base64Encoder implementations.